# error code -532462766 when running project in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a blazor/asp.net project on visual studio code and when using 'dotnet watch' i just receive this error code:
❌ Exited with error code -532462766

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it!

I've tried restarting the project, closing vscode and opening it again but I still get this error code.